# Running two loops in Parallel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I am working on a Video streaming algorithm. I have divided whole video into an array of images. Now each image will be streamed based on the time (`Image.TimeInMs` represents the time at which image to be streamed or sent). To maintain the time I have `System.Timer.Timer` object.

```
_timer = new System.Timers.Timer(250);
_timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timeCounterIncrementer);
_timer.Enabled = true;

for( i =0; i<imageArray.length;i++)
{
    while (timeCounter < imageArray[i].TimeInMs)
    {                          
        StreamImage();
    }
}

void timeCounterIncrementer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    timeCounter+=250;            
}
```

In the above code when the while loop is running timer method `timeCounterIncrementer` will not execute. I want timer method to run on one hand and While loop on the other. In other words How to run the while loop and timer method parallely ?

Comment: Can you use threads and sync the treads instead?

Comment: I can use threads but can not sync. Since both while loop and timer have to executed parallely and more over its video streaming, accuracy in time is the major requirement. Timer value should coincide with the slider value the video player

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently I had a similiar problem. At least I fixed it using [Task Parallelism (Task Parallel Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) since Threading is 2 *hard* for me :)

If you accomplish to part your two loops into methods, you could call these two methods parallely, like this:

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => DoSomeWork(), () => DoSomeOtherWork());
```

Comment: Even I had tried this approach I took the while loop segment placed in a method and then called it as task1 and then I called _timer.start() as task2. But it did not work :(

Comment: What didn't work? Your expectation of what happens, or even the parallel calls?

Comment: I used Parallel.Invoke(() => task1, () => task2); both the calls execute but they are not parallel. I guess since I have timer object which calls a method for every 250milliseconds and this method can not be executed using Parallel.Invoke. If it was two distinct loops then this technique would have worked for me